# How to check in SQL if multi columnar set is in the table (without string concatenation)

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, relational-database, data-warehouse

Let's assume I've 3 columns in a table with values like this:

```
table_1:
   A   |   B   |   C
-----------------------
  'xx' |  ''   |  'y'
  'x'  |  'y'  |  'x'
  'x'  |  'x'  |  'y'
  'x'  |  'yy' |  ''
  'x'  |  ''   |  'yy'
  'x'  |  'y'  |  'y'
```

I've a result set (result of an SQL SELECT statement) which I want to identify in the above table if it exists there:

```
[
    ('x', 'x', 'y')
    ('x', 'y', 'y')
]
```

This result set would match for 5 (of 6) rows in instead of the 2 from the table above if I've compared the results of simple string concatenation, e.g. I would simply compare the results of this: `SELECT concat(A, B, C) FROM table_1`

I could solve this problem with comparing the results of more complex string concatenation functions like this: `SELECT concat('A=', A, '_', 'B=', B, '_', 'C=', C )`

**BUT:**

- I don't want to use any hardcoded special separator in a string concatenation like `_` or `=`

  - because any character might be in the data

    - e.g.: somewhere in column B there might be this value: `xx_C=yy`
  - it's not a clean solution
- I don't want to use string concatenation at all, because it's an ugly solution

  - it makes the "distance" between the attributes disappear
  - not general enough
- maybe I've columns with different datatypes I don't want to convert to a STRING based column

**Question:**

Is it possible to solve somehow this problem without using string concatenation?
Is there a simple solution for this multi column value checking problem?

I want to solve this in BiqQuery, but I'm interested in a general solution for every relational databse/datawarehouse.

Thank you!

---

```
CREATE TABLE test.table_1 (
  A STRING,
  B STRING,
  C STRING
) AS
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 'xx', '', 'y'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'x', 'y', 'x'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'x', 'x', 'y'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'x', 'yy', ''
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'x', '', 'yy'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'x', 'y', 'y'
)

SELECT A, B, C
FROM test.table_1
WHERE (A, B, C) IN (    -> I need this functionality
  SELECT 'x', 'x', 'y'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'x', 'y', 'y'
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the most generic way I can think of (BigQuery Standard SQL):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `project.test.table1` t
WHERE t IN (
  SELECT t
  FROM `project.test.table2` t
)
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.test.table1` AS (
  SELECT 'xx' a, '' b, 'y' c UNION ALL
  SELECT 'x', 'y', 'x' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'x', 'x', 'y' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'x', 'yy', '' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'x', '', 'yy' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'x', 'y', 'y'
), `project.test.table2` AS (
  SELECT 'x' a, 'x' b, 'y' c UNION ALL
  SELECT 'x', 'y', 'y'
)
SELECT *
FROM `project.test.table1` t
WHERE t IN (
  SELECT t
  FROM `project.test.table2` t
)
```

with output

```
Row a   b   c    
1   x   x   y    
2   x   y   y
```

Comment: This is a very good approach, but I've tested with BigQuery and it's not working as expected when using other column types than STRING. I've tested with INT64 based IDs. The same solution works on the tables containing only STRING based columns.

Answer (score 1):

Use `join`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM test.table_1 t1 JOIN
     (SELECT 'x' as a, 'x' as b, 'y' as c
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'x', 'y', 'y'
     ) t2
     USING (a, b, c);
```